# NGINX PHP-FPM 502 error

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, php

I've searched everywhere and cant get this to work at all...

Nginx 1.0.11, php 5.3.2 ubuntu 10.04 lts (fpm-fcgi) with Suhosin v0.9.29

Issue:

I have Joomla and when I create a new article I get 502 bad gateway. If I restart php5-fpm and nginx I can access the page once but when I access again I get the 502. It just seems to be that page...

I've tried

```
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;

fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
```

but none make any difference.

any ideas? Seems like it is the php5-fpm because restarting it lets me access the page once but thats it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, my apc was not configured properly, see what I did below

```
apt-get install libpcre3-dev

pecl install apc

service php5-fpm restart

service nginx restart
```